# How do i save a list of objects in my ViewModel using EF DB Context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model `women` which is part of my db context and a view Model `womenEditmodel` which conatins a list of `women` items. I am using a `partialview` to loop through this list and display an editable Grid or List in my view. These are my models:

```
public class Women
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}

public class WomenEditModel
{
    public List<Women> WomenList { get; set; }
}
```

My view has this loop for injecting into my view rows for the `women` records

```
@foreach (Women women in Model.Womens)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("WomenEditor", women);
}
```

which i display using a `table`. So now users can edit the list and post or save changes.

my partialview looks like:

```
@model XXX.Models.Women
```

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Women")) {                
    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
    </td>        
}
```

My http post action method looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostWomen(WomenEditModel model)
{
    /*I need to iterate through the returned list and save all
    changes to the db.*/

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

How do i loop through the model `WomenEditModel` recieived at the post action method and save changes to the women list back to db?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What does your partial view look like? Are you rendering textboxes with Html.TextBoxFor or EditorFor in the table?

Comment: Hi Nilesh, i have edited my post to include the partialview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got back to my machine. Here is how you can acheive it, if you haven't already.

My Action which renders the list

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Women> womens = new List<Women>
            {
                new Women
                    {
                         Id=1,
                         FirstName = "Women1",
                         LastName = "Lastname1"
                    },
                new Women
                    {
                         Id=2,
                         FirstName = "Women2",
                         LastName = "Lastname2"
                    }
            };
        WomenList womenList=new WomenList();
        womenList.Womens = womens;
        return View(womenList);
    }
```

The action where the list is posted.

```
    public ActionResult SaveWomens(List<Women> womenList)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        //Your save logic goes here
        return View("");
    }
```

Partial View (Dont know whether it is required)

```
@model List<MvcApplication1.Models.Women>
<table>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Id)
            </td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].FirstName)
            </td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].LastName)
            </td>
        </tr> 
    }
</table>
```

And here is the view

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.WomenList
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@section featured {
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveWomens", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
    @Html.Partial("_Women", Model.Womens)

    <input type="submit" value="save" />
}
```

Comment: Hi Nilesh, thank you for the help. My challenge is at SaveWomens action method foreach loop 'foreach (var item in WomenList)' i get an Object reference not set to an instance of an object error. Just can not figure it out.

Comment: That's fine. You can use the code I posted and iterate over the POSTED MODEL. I have checked it and I get a list of Women Objects as input.

Comment: Hi Nilesh, thank you so much. i decided to rework through you example after some rest and it works out well indeed. I am sure this solution will benefit many people. cheers

Comment: Sometimes some rest really helps and I have experienced it :). Good to know you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it as follows

```
 foreach (var item in womenList)
 {
     var obj = new Womens();
     //Assign values to obj for eg: obj.prop = item.prop
     dataContext.Womens.AddObject(obj);                  
 }
 dataContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Hi Jatin, i get at error at the Foreach loop saying Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Just can not figure it out.

Comment: Its may be because your `womenList` is not initialized. Have u debugged and checked it?